# Can anyone point me to the internals on how `<SomeType[]> someJsonArray` works?

Tags: json, typescript

Given a `jsonArray` I can cast it to be taken as an `Array` of `SomeType` Objects using:

```js
<SomeType[]> jsonArray
```

Been `jsonArray` something like:

```js
[
  {
    propertyName: 'value'
  },
  {
    propertyName: 'value'
  }
]
```

Can anyone explain or point me to the docs on how the internals of this work?

Comment: That's not JavaScript

Comment: What language is this? I bet if you search "[language] JSON array type cast" you'll probably find your answer.

Comment: See http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not turning it into anything.  You are casting it to another type.
For example,

```
let foo = [{x:1}, {x: 2}];
foo[0].x; // is valid

function bar(foo: Array<{x: number}>) {
  // can accept foo as a parameter
}
```

Now if you have something that is not typed you can cast it to avoid warnings:

```
bar(<Array<{x: number}>>someVariableOfUnknownType);
```

Comment: That was it. It was just an aweful Angular2 example that was casting a plain Object to prevent warnings.